# CordovaLib missing with Phonegap2.0.0

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am learning phonegap thru online tutorials.
I was creating facebook integration dummy app in xcode using phonegap by following step by step tutorial given at https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

I was able to setup everything but one step where I was asked to add CordovaLib class path to XCODE was not working for me, I tried searching CordovaLib with downloaded and extracted phonegap(2.0.0) but couldn't find same.

At last, after spending good amount of time on google I could get CordovaLib from GITHUB and able to compile my project and make it work.

My question is, if CordovaLib is must for phonegap integration with Xcode, why is it not shipped with phonegap download ?

What is the best way to get CordovaLib in future for newer phonegap versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need anymore.

> Note: Starting with Cordova 2.2, the project will have a copy of CordovaLib within it instead of having a dependency on the copy of CordovaLib from your Cordova installation.

[guide_getting-started_ios](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

Comment: what is the different between Cordova 2.2 and Phonegap 2.2?

Comment: there is no different, just name change